# how much coding skills are required for MS in computer science?

Tags: coding-style, computer-science

okay so i'm pursuing my graduation in **computer science engineering** and I intend to do **MS** in CS but the thing is my coding is not that good.
I have thorough understanding of programming concepts but poor practical application.
I can make all sorting/searching programs and some basics but other than that I don't know much.
could you please help telling me how much should I improve my coding skills for a masters degree?

Answer (score 2):

Learning C in depth is very important for career in computer science, only when you begin. Once you entered any particular job/field, say Web design, Linux Driver coding, SAP, ASIC/Verilog, embedded programming etc.. etc.. then the language you have used in that particular job/field is more important - because when you switch job you will asked question in that area.